# Regex for Nginx with dynamic subdirectory element in URL

Tags: regex, nginx

I've got several applications installed in subdirectories with a name structure like `id random string`:

> 17aefk
>   18kauf
>   19naku

Now I was playing around with my Nginx config and got it working like:

```
    location /17aefk/ {
        try_files $uri /17aefk/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

But I'd like to have a working location for all folders, so it would need to be a reg ex I guess. But this is where I'm struggeling.

```
location ^/(.+)/? {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Is just resulting into an error `open() "/var/www/domain/17aefk/index.php/s/dashboard" failed (20: Not a directory)`

Can I somehow get a better debugging view or can you see my (regex) issue right away?

Edit:
`domain.com/17aefk/index.php` which forwards me to `domain.com/17aefk/index.php/s/dashboard` (due the web app logic)

Comment: `domain.com/17aefk/index.php` which forwards me to `domain.com/17aefk/index.php/s/dashboard` (due the web app logic)

Comment: In that case `open()` error might be coming from your code.

Comment: I think the code is working well since my first examples works great.
When I want to have a dynamic URL structure supported it doesn't work anymore - so only those changes throw an error message. That makes me feel it can only be the Nginx config.

Comment: When you have first example only does it not redirect to `domain.com/17aefk/index.php/s/dashboard`?

Comment: It does as well, but everything is working fine with the first example. Site is being loaded, no errors in the Nginx log. 
Changing to the second example, site isn't being loaded and I've got the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting specific pattern of your dynamic folders:

```
location ~ ^/\d+[a-zA-Z]+/ {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. With this approach the index.php file is offered as a download. So it seems to change sth. but not yet entirely correct. How can php execute it instead of me downloading it?

Comment: I don't know all the details but try: `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;`